# Python Requests library fails to make succesfull POST (Nanotec motor controller)

Tags: python, rest, web, python-requests

I have a motor controller that runs a REST web service which I want to control using Python.

I am able to successfully perform GET requests using the Python requests library. I am however not able to perform POST requests. It gives me the following error:

```
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: ('Connection aborted.', RemoteDisconnected('Remote end closed connection without response'))
```

I suspect that the web service crashes because I sometimes have to restart the motor controller to get GET requests working again. Here is the python code I am using to perform the POST:

```
import requests

url = 'http://192.168.178.199/od/607A/00'
headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
data = '00000002'

response = requests.post(url, headers=headers, data=data)

print(response.content)
```

I am however able to successfully perform POST requests using the following Curl command:

```
curl -X POST -H 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' -i 'http://192.168.178.199/od/607A/00' --data '"00000003"'

HTTP/1.0 200 OK
Server: uip/1.0
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, private
Content-type: application/json
```

The python code should be exactly the same right? What am I missing?

FYI: The motor controller I am using is a nanotec n5-2-3. Manual with info on the REST service can be found here:
https://en.nanotec.com/fileadmin/files/Handbuecher/Handbuecher_Archiv/Steuerungen/N5/fir-v2039/N5_EtherNetIP_Technical-Manual_V3.2.0.pdf

Comment: Well, your curl version is sending double-quotes around the number, your Python code is just sending the number.  I can't make enough sense out of the documentation to tell which, if either, is correct.

Comment: @jasonharper I also tried the double-quotes in Python with the same response. And yeah the REST service documentation is really bad.

Comment: My next suggestion would be to use WireShark or other packet sniffer to see exactly what the difference is between what curl and Python are sending.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same behaviour with a nanotec drive unit. I could update the object dictionary with curl:

```
curl -X POST http://192.168.2.21/od/3701/00 -d '"0002"'
```

but not with the python requests library.

I overcame this by writing the requests manually using the socket library. The code for GET and POST requests are below.

```
import socket

def POST(host, target, value):
    '''
    host = base url or ip.
    target = everything after base url
    value = content of body
    
    For example POST('192.168.2.2', '/temp/od', '"0006"')
    would send a POST request to 192.168.2.2/temp/od with a 
    body containing the value "0006" (including the speech marks).
    '''
    post_request = f"""POST {target} HTTP/1.0\r\nHost: {host}\r\nContent-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\nContent-Length: {len(value)}\r\n\r\n{value}"""
    
    # Create a socket object
    # The two input parameters are the defaults.
    # They specify the type of address and socket.
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

    # Connect to the server
    s.connect((host, 80)) # Assuming the server is listening on port 80

    print(post_request)
    print("---"*5)
    
    # Send the POST request
    s.send(post_request.encode())

    # Receive the response
    response = s.recv(4096)

    # Print the response
    print(response.decode())

    # Close the socket
    s.close()
    

def GET(host, target):
    '''
    host = base url or ip.
    target = everything after base url
    '''
    # Prepare the HTTP GET request
    get_request = f"GET {target} HTTP/1.0\r\nHost: {host}\r\n\r\n"

    # Create a socket object
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

    # Connect to the drive unit
    s.connect((host, 80)) # Assuming the server is listening on port 80

    # Send the GET request
    s.send(get_request.encode())

    # Receive the response, 4096 is just recommended by docs
    response = s.recv(4096)

    # Print the response
    decoded = response.decode()
    print(decoded)

    # Close the socket
    s.close()

    # Return the body content
    return decoded.split('\r\n\r\n')[-1]
```

I was then able to update the object dictionary with the POST function:

```py
host = '192.168.2.21'
target = '/od/3701/00'

POST(host, target, '"0002"')
```

and read it with the GET function:

```py
response = GET(host, target)
```